# Responsive Curve line between elements

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, responsive

I'm currently working on a project that has two columns with text, headings and buttons. I would like to keep the design responsive, but when our client adds more text to "Step 3" the SVG doesn't line up correctly.

**My thoughts**
I would like to remove the SVG and set "anchor" points to the paragraph text boxes and create a curved dotted line between those anchor points.

**The question is:**
How do I achieve this?

[Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbAdc.png)

I tried to use an SVG and scale it with the content, but this didn't work as expected.
After watching different solutions on forums, I didn't succeed in finding a solution.

This is the structure of the bock seen on the screenshot.
I am using Tailwindcss for my styling.

```html
        <section class="container mx-auto background mb-52">
            <div class="flex flex-row">

                <div class="flex flex-col justify-center relative max-w-[534px]">
                    <img class=" max-w-[534px] max-h-[575px]" src="https://via.placeholder.com/534x575.png" alt="">
                </div>

                <div class="ml-28 flex flex-row">

                    <div class="max-w-[315px]">
                        <!-- Item 1 -->
                        <div class="text-left p-3">
                            <div class="">
                                <h1 class="text-xl py-2"><span class="font-bold">1. </span>TITLE</h1>
                                <p class="font-roboto font-light">
                                    text
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="py-4 flex flex-wrap">
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Online strategie</a>
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Vindbaarheid</a>
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Webdesign</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Item 3 -->
                        <div class="text-left p-3 ">
                            <div class="">
                                <h1 class="text-xl py-2"><span class="font-bold">3. </span>TITLE</h1>
                                <p class="font-roboto font-light">
                                Text
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="py-4 flex flex-wrap">
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Klantportalen</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Item 5 -->
                        <div class="text-left p-3 ">
                            <div class="">
                                <h1 class="text-xl py-2"><span class="font-bold">5. </span>TITLE</h1>
                                <p class="font-roboto font-light">
                                Text
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="py-4 flex flex-wrap">
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Conversie optimalisatie</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                <!-- Col IMG -->
                
                <div class="my-auto max-h-[764px] max-w-[100px] flex flex-col justify-center">
                    <img class="w-full" src="{{ asset('storage/images/curvy-line.svg') }}" alt="">
                </div>

                
                    <div class="my-auto max-w-[315px]">
                

                        <!-- Item 2 -->
                        <div class="text-left p-3 ">
                            <div class="">
                                <h1 class="text-xl py-2"><span class="font-bold">2. </span>TITLE</h1>
                                <p class="font-roboto font-light">
                                Text
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="py-4 flex flex-wrap">
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Koppelingen</a>
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">E-Commerce</a>
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Productconfiguratoren</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Item 4 -->
                        <div class="text-left p-3 ">
                            <div class="">
                                <h1 class="text-xl py-2"><span class="font-bold">4. </span>TITLE</h1>
                                <p class="font-roboto font-light">
                                Text
                                </p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="py-4 flex flex-wrap">
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Bedrijfapps</a>
                                <a href="" class="m-1 px-4 py-3.5 text-primary text-sm border-2 font-semibold border-primary hover:bg-primary hover:text-white transition duration-300">Dashboarding</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div>

                
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Please add enough code into your question so we can understand the problem. At the moment we would have no clue how to answer your query as we don't know what your HTML structure is or what the SVG is or where is it supposed to be. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, I have made some changes to my Question. I did upload the wrong image beforehand. but i fixed it and also added the source code.

Comment: Hi Dani, welcome to SO!  Maybe open source [LeaderLine](https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/) will work for you...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, Ill try to fit it in with my project!!

Comment: I can't see the SVG - and it seems to 'bump into [nearly]' each block of text in a different place relative to the height of the block - what is the actual requirement?